# Zookeeper deletes logs on restart

Tags: java, log4j, apache-zookeeper

Everytime that I restart zookeeper it truncates the file `/var/log/zookeeper/instance/zookeeper.out`.
I would like to change this behaviour in a way that it always appends the lines to that log file so that I can see for example the cause of a crash.

Zookeeper version: 3.5.4-beta

Comment: Kindly add zookeeper version

Comment: sorry for the miss. It's 3.5.4-beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `zookeeper-xxx.log` is the log file instead of `zookeeper.out`

A solution is to modify `zkEnv.sh` and set

```
ZOO_LOG4J_PROP=LOG_LEVEL,ROLLINGFILE
```

(LOG_LEVEL = DEBUG / INFO etc) directly.

Note: Look into zkServer.sh which is the script used to start ZooKeeper, you can find the real java command to start ZooKeeper, and it does take -Dzookeeper.root.logger=XXX as one of its arguments. Also, this is where -Dzookeeper.root.logger is coming from, you’ll see it’s set in zkEnv.sh.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, looking inside the zkServer.sh made me understand that the script was not launched with the correct paramethers by systemd